# MayTag Legacy Series Top of Dryer Won't Open

Tags: repair, appliances, dryer

I can not open the top of my Maytag Legacy Series Dryer. There is a screw on each side of the top of the dryer pinning it down to the base? What do I do now to get to the rest of the dryer since the top can't open?

Comment: Repair manuals for most home appliances can be found or purchased on line these days; that's probably the wasiest way to get instructions for your specific model. For mine, the first step was to remove the front panel,.

Comment: Most have spring clips on the left and right front edge of the top panel. Once the screws are removed a gently pry with a tool at the front left and right corners will pop the clips up. Then you lift the front edge and pull toward you to release a couple of notched tabs in the right and left rear.